# Accessing static functions/variable from different threads

Tags: c, multithreading, static

I use a third side library written in C. It is designed to run as singleton and contains plenty of static functions, variables and user interface. I need to be able to run it with multiple instances so they do not interfere with each other. For example if one threads sets static variable

```
static int index = 0;
index = 10;
```

the second thread still sees index = 0. 
I am not sure if it is even possible to implement.

Comment: You could modify all the static variables to be thread-local variables perhaps

Comment: It is nearly impossible with 1000 files mutexes locks etc.

Comment: You'll need to put each thread (corresponding to an instance of the library) in its own process to make this work.

Comment: What is your target OS? *nix or Windows?

Comment: 'one threads sets static variable' just don't do that.  It's that simple - if you want to have thread-safe functions, (eg. unlike strtok), don't use static vars.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible.

Let's assume for pedagogical purposes that you are on a unix machine.

Any process (such as the executable ./a.out) has the following Memory layout :

1. Text
2. Data

   - Initialized
   - Uninitialized
3. Heap
4. Stack

When you create a thread, then it shares all these memory segments **except** the *Stack* section(basically each thread gets a new stack pointer).

Moreover the static variables are stored in the *Data* segment (in your case Initialized data segment) which is a shared memory segment, hence when one thread changes it, it changes for all other threads as well.

So threads only have the following things local to themself

- Stack pointer
- Program Counter
- registers

[image: memory layout for multithreaded processes]

Image source : [llnl.gov](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

Hope it helped :-).